# Draw lines with flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Is there any way to display skew borders at the top and bottom?
I came up with the solution below by using two images (top_layout and bottom_layout.png). Is there any other way to make those color bars with shadows without using static images?

```
return Container(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 236, 0, 140),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          margin:
              EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0, bottom: 20.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned.fill(
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/imgs/top_layout.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned.fill(
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/imgs/xbottom_layout.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

## How do draw lines in Flutter using the CustomPaint widget

[image]

To paint in Flutter you use the [`CustomPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) widget. The `CustomPaint` widget takes a [`CustomPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) object as a parameter. In that class you have to override the `paint` method, which gives you a canvas that you can paint on. Here is the code to draw the line in the image above.

```
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  final p1 = Offset(50, 50);
  final p2 = Offset(250, 150);
  final paint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.black
    ..strokeWidth = 4;
  canvas.drawLine(p1, p2, paint);
}
```

Notes:

- The `drawLine` method draws a line connecting the two points you give it.
- An `Offset` is a pair of `(dx, dy)` doubles, offset from the top left corner of the `CustomPaint` widget.

#### Another option

You could do something similar with the `drawPoints` method using the `PointMode.polygon` option.

[image]

```
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  final pointMode = ui.PointMode.polygon;
  final points = [
    Offset(50, 100),
    Offset(150, 75),
    Offset(250, 250),
    Offset(130, 200),
    Offset(270, 100),
  ];
  final paint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.black
    ..strokeWidth = 4
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
  canvas.drawPoints(pointMode, points, paint);
}
```

#### Context

Here is the *main.dart* code so that you can see it in context.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: HomeWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: CustomPaint( //                       <-- CustomPaint widget
        size: Size(300, 300),
        painter: MyPainter(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter { //         <-- CustomPainter class
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    //                                             <-- Insert your painting code here.
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter old) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

#### See also

See [this article](https://medium.com/@studymongolian/how-to-paint-in-flutter-d18c6c26df10) for my fuller answer.