# How can I draw a widget on top of a widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I want to draw a yellow arrow over the 9 blue squares as shown in the picture below.

[image: Question Image]

But I don't know which widget to use to draw arrows freely on each rectangle. I want to draw an arrow like a screen lock pattern. I would like to know the different ways in which this arrow can be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the whole Containers inside a `Stack` widget and then paint the line by using the `CustomPaint` widget shown in this question [Draw lines with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661354/draw-lines-with-flutter).

```dart
Stack(
      children: [
        Arrow(child: Container()),
        ContainerWidgets(),
      ],
    )
```

And for the painter:

```dart
class Arrow extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Add your paint logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I'll try your idea